# What is the meaning of this $\begin{equation*} \mathrm{E}\left\{ g(x)\right\} \underset{x\in X}{\rightarrow }\min \end{equation*}$

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, convex-optimization

I would like to understand this paragraph:

Let $g(x):\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a $x$-differentiable
function and let $x_{1},x_{2},...$ be a sequence of measurement points for
which the values $y_{1},y_{2},...$ of the function $g(x)$ is accessible to
observation at every discrete-time $n=1,2,...$ and considering the aditive
noise $\xi _{n}$ we have that
\begin{equation*}
y_{n}=g(x)+\xi _{n}
\end{equation*}
Then, considering the sequence of estimated values $\left\{ \hat{x}%
_{n}\right\} $ the goal in stochastic optimization problems is to find a
fixed point $x^{\ast }$ that satisfies the system of the extreme inclusion%
\begin{equation*}
\mathrm{E}\left\{ g(x)\right\} \underset{x\in X}{\rightarrow }\min
\end{equation*}.

First what is the meaning of $\mathrm{E}\left\{ g(x)\right\} \underset{x\in X}{\rightarrow }\min$ this is a kind of expectation in probability or what?
And second why do I need a "noise" in stochastic problems?

Hope someone could help me to understand this please.

Comment: Can you tell where this is from? $E\{g(x)\}\underset{x\in X}{\rightarrow}min$ could mean minimization of the expectation of $g(x)$ w.r.t. $x\in X$. Noise plays the role of uncertainty of the observation. Without noise(or another source of randomness) this would be a deterministic problem and stochastic optimization would make no sense.

Comment: It's simply an uncommon, alternative way to write $$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & E\{g(x)\} \\ \text{subject to} & x\in X \end{array}$$ Nothing more complicated than that.